# jqgrid rename search dialog drop down item

Tags: jqgrid

The Search dialog has a drop down item named is in. I like to rename that to something different: Is between

Is it possible to rename it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need you can use `odata` option . See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ClientsideEditing3.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3335982/315935) where you will see the operation "from".

Answer (score 0):

On your jqgrid column, change "SearchToolBarOperation" to what operation you need.